# Javascript set var inside var

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I am creating a basic roll the dice program for Discord, and i would like to know how to set a variable in a variable. I may be over complicating things, but I still want to see if this is possible and if there is a better way to do this. This is my current code:

```js
    while (dice > 0) {
        var die = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1)
        console.log("roll: " + die + ", currently: " + dice)
        dice = dice - 1
        message.channel.sendMessage(die)
    }
```

So currently this does the job 'well'. I'm looking to store the `dice` variable (the part where you define how many dice to throw) with a `roll` variable. I'm guessing it would be something like

    `var roll = r.dice`

Basically, all I am trying to do is save the rolls as different variables to send them in one message. So the code would save them as r.10 to r.1, then I can present those variables as one message

    `r.10
    .
    .
    r.1`

Is that possible with the methods I'm using, or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want JS objects or arrays?

Comment: You may be looking to create an array of dice rolls. In this case, it would be trivial to link each roll with each index of the array. To concatenate this into a single message, do something like this: [2, 5, 6, 2, 6, 1, 6].map(function(value, index) { return "r." + (index + 1) + ": " + value; }).join('\n');

Comment: Never mind about the part where i said i needed help with a variable inside a variable, I found that out (var roll = "r." + dice) But still, is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array:

This example will generate 10 dice rolls, add them into the array `roll`, and then output the array as a single message.

```js
var roll = [];
var dice = 10;
while (dice --> 0) {
  var die = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  roll.push(die);
}
var output = roll.map((x, i) => {
  return 'r.' + (roll.length - i) + ': ' + x;
}).join('\n');

console.log(output);
//message.channel.sendMessage(output)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me, I _somewhat_ understand what's going on, but all in all thank you. One slight problem that i did not have before, is that the numbers can go above 6, some examples are 14, 12, 7, 10. Could this be fixable? I don't quite know why it's going above, all i edited in the code was removing the "r." and the ":" replacing the "\n" with a ", ", so it output a clean line of numbers. Any way this is resolvable?

Comment: Did you leave a space between `(roll.length - i)` and `x` when removing the `:`?  The only reason I could think of for you getting a result above 6 is if it's adding the die number to the result.

Comment: Yeah, that did happen. A little bit before you responded, i looked for a pattern to help and seeing what made it go over, and not it's just a ''. Thank you for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doRolls(numRolls)
{ 
    var rolls = [];
    for (var i=0; i < numRolls; i++) {
      rolls.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1) + 1))
    }
    return rolls;
}

rolls = doRolls(10);

for (var i=0; i < rolls.length; i++) {
    console.log("roll: " + i + ", value: " + rolls[i])
    message.channel.sendMessage(rolls[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rolls = []
for (var n = 0; n < 10; n += 1) {
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    rolls.push(roll);
}

console.log(rolls);

for (var n = 0; n < 10; n += 1) {
    console.log("Roll number", n, "->", rolls[n]);
}
```

Comment: **From Review**: This answer was flagged as **low quality**. While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)